# Integration Using Inverse Trig Functions

Tags: integration

> $$\int \frac{1}{(36-4x^2)^{0.5}} dx$$

You can immediately see that,

$$6^2 = 36$$

And,

$$(2x)^2 = 4x^2$$

Using the integration technique as follows:

$$\int \frac{1}{(a^2-x^2)^{0.5}} dx = \arcsin(\frac{x}{a})+C$$

We get,

$$\int \frac{1}{(36-4x^2)^{0.5}} dx = \int \frac{1}{(6^2-(2x)^2)^{0.5}} dx$$

Where $a = 6$ and $x = 2x$. Substituting this into the above general rule, we get

$$\int \frac{1}{(6^2-(2x)^2)^{0.5}} dx = \arcsin(\frac{2x}{6})+C$$

> $$=\arcsin(\frac{x}{3})+C$$

However, using this same procedure when we split the denominator gives us a different result:

$$\int \frac{1}{(36-4x^2)^{0.5}} dx = \int \frac{1}{((4)(9-x^2))^{0.5}} dx$$

$$=\int \frac{1}{(4)^{0.5}(9-x^2)^{0.5}} dx$$

$$=\int \frac{1}{2(9-x^2)^{0.5}} dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{(9-x^2)^{0.5}} dx$$

Here, $a = 3$ and $x = x$ to give:

> $$ = \frac{1}{2}\arcsin(\frac{x}{3})+C$$

Why are both results different? Through differentiation I know that the second result is correct - why does a direct substitution into the general formula yield an incorrect answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the issue. The general form is $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx=\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C,$$

but your integral is

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{6^2-(2x)^2}}\,dx.$$

The $2x$ is different than $x$. The difference can be eliminated by making the substitution $2x=u$, so $dx=du/2$, and we get

$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{6^2-u^2}}\,du=\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{u}{6}\right)+C=\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+C.$$

Comment: But I did account for the 2x...didn't I? I substituted x with 2x to end up with the same argument of the arcsin. I'm still not sure...it still seems to me that a very simple substitution in the general formula is giving me an incorrect result, as if the general formula has exceptions...if you don't mind, could you elaborate?

Comment: Substituting $2x$ into the general form of the integral is good, but it is not enough. The general form is very specific, you need to have $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ in the denominator, not $\sqrt{a^2-(2x)^2}.$ You have to match the general form exactly in order to use it. It's not enough just to make the substitution. Using the general form is just not valid unless you match it exactly.

Comment: Oh I see! That really cleared it up. Thanks a lot for your time!